# Error while sending data using SIM800 in Arduino Mega

Tags: android, arduino, embedded, tcp

I am working on an college project in which I have to use an Arduino mega with a GSM module (SIM800) to send the sensor data through GPRS on an Android application using a TCP server.

When I am executing `AT+CIPSEND`, I am getting an error in HyperTerminal (see the attached screen shot and coding).

Arduino code:

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

unsigned int k7, k = 0, a, b, r = 0;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0, currentMillis;
unsigned long time, i, k1;
const long interval = 5000;
double alpha = 0.75;
static double oldValue = 0;
static double oldChange = 0;
int hb = i; //heart beat sensor pin
int rs = 30; //respiration sensor input
int bz = 40; //buzzer output pin
int vi = 45; //vibration output pin

void gsm_init(void);
void Gprs_Init();
void gprs_Send_deat(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int);
void value(int);

unsigned char num[12] = "7709751376";
void setup()
{
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial3.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("  SLEEP APNEA   ");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("   USING IOT    ");
  delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000);
  delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000);
  delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000);
  delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000);
  pinMode(hb, INPUT);
  pinMode(rs, INPUT);
  pinMode(bz, INPUT);
  pinMode(vi, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(bz, LOW);
  digitalWrite(vi, LOW);
  lcd.clear();
  gsm_init();
  Gprs_Init();
}
void loop()
{
  a = analogRead(A0);   //ECG sensor input

  if (digitalRead(hb) == HIGH)
  {
    i++;
    if (i > 2500)
    {
      i = 0;
      r++;
    }
  }

  if (digitalRead(rs) == LOW)
  {
    k1++;
    if (k1 > 2000)
    {
      k1 = 0;
      k++;
    }
  }
  if (k > 20)
  {
    k = 12;
  }
  currentMillis = millis();
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval)
  {
    r = (r * 5) + 10;
    k += 02;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("HB:");
    lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
    lcd.print(r);

    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("RES:");
    lcd.setCursor(4, 1);
    lcd.print("   ");
    lcd.setCursor(4, 1);
    lcd.print(k);

    lcd.setCursor(8, 0);
    lcd.print("ECG:");
    lcd.setCursor(12, 0);
    lcd.print(a);
    if ((k >= 8 && k <= 15) && (r >= 60 && r <= 80))
    {
      lcd.setCursor(7, 1);
      lcd.print("  NORMAL ");
      digitalWrite(bz, LOW);
      digitalWrite(vi, LOW);
      delay(3000);
    }
    if (((k >= 8 && k <= 15) && (r >= 60 && r <= 80)) != 1)
    {
      lcd.setCursor(7, 1);
      lcd.print("ABNORMAL ");
      digitalWrite(bz, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(vi, HIGH);
      delay(3000);
    }
    if (a > 999)
    {
      a = 565;
    }
    gprs_Send_deat(r, k, a);
    k = 0;
    r = 0;
    previousMillis = millis();
  }
}
void gsm_init()
{
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("  gsm init....  ");
  Serial3.println("AT"); delay(1000);
  Serial3.println("AT+CMGF=1"); delay(1000);
  Serial3.println("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0"); delay(1000);
  delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000);
}

void Gprs_Init()
{
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("CONNECTING GPRS ");
  Serial3.print("AT+CGATT?"); //GET GPRS SERVICE STATUS
  Serial3.write(0X0D);
  Serial3.write(0X0A);
  delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000);

  Serial3.print("AT+CIPSHUT"); //CLOSE ALL CONNECTION
  Serial3.write(0X0D);
  Serial3.write(0X0A);
  delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000);

  Serial3.print("AT+CIPSTATUS"); //QUERY CURRENT STATUS
  Serial3.write(0X0D);
  Serial3.write(0X0A);
  delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000);

  Serial3.print("AT+CIPMUX=0");//SET TCPIP CONNECTION MODE TO 0 FOR SINGLE CONNECTION ,1 FOR MULTI CONNECTION
  Serial3.write(0X0D);
  Serial3.write(0X0A);
  delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000);

  Serial3.print("AT+CIPCSGP=1");
  Serial3.write(',');
  Serial3.write('"');
  Serial3.print("airtelgprs.pr");
  Serial3.write('"');
  Serial3.write(0X0D);
  Serial3.write(0X0A);
  delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000);

  Serial3.print("AT+CLPORT=");//Set Local UDP/TCP Port
  Serial3.write('"');
  Serial3.print("TCP");
  Serial3.write('"');
  Serial3.write(',');
  Serial3.write('"');
  Serial3.print("6001");
  Serial3.write('"');
  Serial3.write(0X0D);
  Serial3.write(0x0A);
  delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000);

  Serial3.print("AT+CSTT=");// START TASK AND SET APN
  Serial3.write('"');
  Serial3.print("airtelgprs.pr");
  Serial3.write('"');
  Serial3.write(',');
  Serial3.write('"');
  Serial3.write('"');
  Serial3.write(',');
  Serial3.write('"');
  Serial3.write('"');
  Serial3.write(0X0D);
  Serial3.write(0X0A);
  delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000);
  while (Serial3.available())
    Serial3.read();
  Serial3.print("AT+CIICR"); //BRING UP GPRS CONNECTION
  Serial3.write(0X0D);
  Serial3.write(0X0A);
  delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000);
  Serial3.print("AT+CIFSR");//GET LOCAL IP
  delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000); delay(1000);
  Serial3.write(0X0D);
  Serial3.write(0X0A);
  while (Serial.available())
    Serial3.read();
  Serial3.print("AT+CIPSERVER=1");//START SERVER IN SINGLE CONNECTION MODE OR GIVEN PORT
  Serial3.write(',');
  Serial3.print("8000");//SERVER PORT
  Serial3.write(0X0D);
  Serial3.write(0X0A);
  while (Serial3.available())
    Serial3.read();
  delay(2000); delay(1000); delay(1000);
  delay(2000); delay(1000); delay(1000);
  delay(2000); delay(1000); delay(1000);
  static char buff[120];
  static int rx;
  while (Serial3.available())
    buff[rx++] = Serial3.read();

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(" IP ADDRESS,,,,,");
  for (k7 = 23; k7 < 38; k7++)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(0 + k7 - 23, 1);
    lcd.write(buff[k7]);
  }
  delay(3000);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("  SEND IP ADDR  ");
  Serial3.print("AT+CMGS=");//SEND IP ADDRESS ON GIVEN NUMBER
  Serial3.print("\"");
  for (k7 = 0; k7 < 10; k7++)
  {
    Serial3.write(num[k7]);
  }
  Serial3.print("\"");
  delay(1000);
  Serial3.write(0x0D);
  Serial3.write(0x0A);
  delay(1000);
  Serial3.println("your ip address:");
  for (k7 = 23; k7 < 38; k7++)
  {
    Serial3.write(buff[k7]);
  }
  delay(1000);
  Serial3.write(0x1A);
  delay(3000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("MSG SEND FINISHED");
  delay(3000);
  lcd.clear();
}
void gprs_Send_deat(unsigned int rat1, unsigned int k2, unsigned int a1)
{
  lcd.setCursor(7, 1);
  lcd.print("DATA SEND");
  delay(1000);
  Serial3.print("AT+CIPSEND"); //SEND DATA TO CONNECTION
  Serial3.write(0X0D);
  Serial3.write(0X0A);
  delay(1000);
  Serial3.write('*');
  Serial1.write('*');
  value(rat1);  //Heart beat
  value(k2);    //respiration
  value(a1);    //ECG
  Serial3.write(0X0D);
  Serial3.write(0X0A);
  delay(2000);
  Serial3.write(0x1A);
  delay(2000);
  lcd.setCursor(7, 1);
  lcd.print("Completed");
  delay(1000);
  lcd.setCursor(7, 1);
  lcd.print(" update  ");
}
void value(int e)
{
  int q, g, h, w;
  q = e / 100;
  g = e % 100;
  h = g / 10;
  w = g % 10;
  Serial3.write(q + 0x30);
  Serial3.write(h + 0x30);
  Serial3.write(w + 0x30);
  Serial1.write(q + 0x30);
  Serial1.write(h + 0x30);
  Serial1.write(w + 0x30);
  delay(500);
}
```

HyperTerminal:

[image: Hyper Terminal]

Comment: Are you using an Arduino for medtech applications!? Sounds criminal.

Comment: No i am using this for sending heartbeat ,respiration sensor data to android application

Answer (score 0):

First of all make SIM800 to full functionality using

```
AT+CFUN=1
```

Then follow below sequence :

```
AT+CIPSHUT  
AT+CGATT=0  
AT+CGATT=1  
AT+CGDCONT=1,IP,"Your APN NAME"
AT+CIPMODE=0
AT+CGACT=1,1
AT+CSTT="Your APN Name"
AT+CIICR
AT+CIFSR
AT+CLPORT="TCP","2020"
```

After this response **OK**, you can try sending data to server.
Please make sure you get Ok response for all of the above, otherwise try printing Error code and check that Error in details in Datasheet.
You can get it [Here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjInZyEiqXWAhXKuo8KHUyACbMQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.elecrow.com%2Fdownload%2FSIM800%2520Series_AT%2520Command%2520Manual_V1.09.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFniJw4IMqSv3M7ZiGU5hIw8djJEw) on page no 343